# How does a laser actually neutralise a static electric charge?

Tags: electrostatics, laser

Eg in a Laser printer or a photocopier, a Laser is used to neutralise the charged drum (so the charged toner only collects where it is required.)
but what is the process by which the charge is neutralised by the photon striking it?

Answer (score 1):

The drum in a photocopier is coated in a material that is an insulator in the dark but becomes conducting when light shines on it.

This is actually a common feature of materials with a band gap equal to or less than the energy of visible light. Under these circumstances the energy in the light excites electrons from the valence band into the conduction band. This produces mobile positively charged holes in the valence band and mobile negatively charged electrons in the conduction band, and both flow in response to an electic field.

So when the light hits the drum the illuminated areas become conducting and the charge flows away to earth.